# Неисправность при заполнении данных в input

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть у меня такой вот скрипт, дело в том что когда без заполнении данных нажимаю на Send подчеркиваются все 3 input-а (так и должно быть), но когда я ввожу внутри одного из троих input-ов у меня должно этот же input стать серым (как было вначале), но такого не происходит,  происходит только тогда когда я ввожу второй input, плюс к этому когда input-и стали серыми (две input-и после ввода), когда нажимается send все 3 элемента становятся красными вместо одного (в которого не вводили ничего), есть ли какой ни будь способ исправить это кроме присвоении отдельных классов и отдельных функции?

css и html добавил всего лишь для вида, ошибка в jQuery

```
input{
  outline:none;
  border:1px solid #EDEDED;
}
.send{
    width:155px;
    height:23px;
    background-color:#5089FC;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color:white;
    border-radius:20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 85px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
.msg{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 15;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.msg-sec{
    width:60%;
    height:30%;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #BABABA;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.msg-sec>p{
    color:#5089FC;
}
.msg-sec>i{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;
    right: -10px;
    top:-10px;
    color:red;
}


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input type = "text" placeholder="" class = "input-adress input">
<input type="text" name="" placeholder = "+7" class = "input-numb input">
<input type="mail" name="" class = "input">

<div class = "msg">
        <div class = "msg-sec">
            <p>Данные отправлены</p>
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle close-end"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class = "send">Send</div>




$(".send").click(function(){
    if($(".input").val() == ""){
        $(".input").css("border", "red solid 1px");
    }
    else if($(".input").val() !== ""){
        $('.alert').css('display','flex');
        $(".input").val('')
        $(".preview").attr("src","");
    }
})

$(".close-end").click(function(){
    $('.alert').css('display','none');
})



document.querySelectorAll(".input").forEach(el => el.oninput = noneRed);




function noneRed(){
    if($(".input").val() !== ""){
        $(".input").css("border", "#EDEDED solid 1px");
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы специально не оформляете вопросы, как положено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При выполнении функции nonred Вы всё равно проверяете только первое значение. 
Вам необходимо выполнять данное действия для каждого элемента `input`, а не только первого. 
Так же в пример добавил использование localstorage. Чтобы по 100 раз не приходилось вводить данные. При желании можете закомментировать просто вызов этой функции.

```js
    $(".send").click(function () {
        $(".input").each(function (key,inp) { // Выполняем для каждого поля input
            localStorage.setItem(key, $(inp).val()); // Сохраняем значение в localstorage
            if ($(inp).val() == "") { // Проверяем заполнено ли.
                $(inp).css("border", "red solid 1px"); // inp
            } else if ($(inp).val() !== "") {
                $('.alert').css('display', 'flex');
                $(inp).val('');
                $(".preview").attr("src", "");
            }
        });
        setVal(); // вызываем функцию.
    });

    $(".close-end").click(function () {
        $('.alert').css('display', 'none');
    });

    document.querySelectorAll(".input").forEach(el => el.oninput = function () { // вводим функию, где работаем с переменной el (ранее не передавалась в функцию Вашу)
        if($(el).val()!==''){
            $(el).css("border", "#EDEDED solid 1px");
        }
    });

    function setVal() {
        $(".input").each(function (key1, inp1) {
            let tempval = localStorage.getItem(key1); // Берём значение из localstorage по ключу
            if (tempval) { // если есть, то...
                inp1.value = tempval; // Проставляем значение
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
    input{
    outline:none;
    border:1px solid #EDEDED;
}
.send{
    width:155px;
    height:23px;
    background-color:#5089FC;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color:white;
    border-radius:20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 85px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
.msg{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 15;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.msg-sec{
    width:60%;
    height:30%;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #BABABA;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.msg-sec>p{
    color:#5089FC;
}
.msg-sec>i{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;
    right: -10px;
    top:-10px;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type = "text" placeholder="" class = "input-adress input">
<input type="text" name="" placeholder = "+7" class = "input-numb input">
<input type="mail" name="" class = "input">

<div class = "msg">
        <div class = "msg-sec">
            <p>Данные отправлены</p>
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle close-end"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class = "send">Send</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь и потраченного вами времени, а можно ли сделать так чтобы при заполнении данных если не все заполнены то $('.alert').css('display', 'flex'); не сработал

Comment: @Мнебезсахара, Да, конечно. Только поясните, пожалуйста, чуть конкретнее. В случае, если хотя бы одно поле не заполнено должен быть алерт или наоборот только когда все три поля не заполнены?

Comment: я уже решил задачу по другому, но все же не помешает этот вариант). нужно сделать так, чтобы когда человек пропускает хоть один input (всмысле не заполняет), то этот же элемент должен подсвечиватся красным, и alert в таком случае не должен работать